# AviSynth can't open my AVI file: “AVISource: Couldn't locate a decompressor for fourcc dvds”

Tags: codec, avi, avisynth, virtualdub

I simply want to open an AVI file with AviSynth and feed it into VirtualDub. However, when I open my `.avs` script (consisting of just one `AviSource()` call), I get the following error:

> Avisynth open failure:
>       AVISource: Couldn't locate a decompressor for fourcc dvds
>       (H:\Videos\QTGMC\test.avs, line 1)

The required dvsd codec seems to be installed, according to software called GSpot (which identifies a video file's required codec's). Does anyone know why I can't open this file and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone has the same issue in the future, I solved it by installing Cedocida codec: http://www.cithraidt.de/cedocida/index.html#download.

Using `DirectShowSource()` instead of `AviSource()` also works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FmpegSource2()](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/FFmpegSource) - it does not use codecs from the system like `AVISource()` or `DirectShowSource()` and recognizes a lot of modern format with frame accuracy.

Basically, it supports all the formats FFMPEG does.